# Attaching a ring-like handle to a castle door

Tags: design

I'd like to attach a round metal looking handle to a castle door such as [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2554&C=11#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D).

I did a search for 'ring' on Bricklink and found the [life preserver.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30340&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Flotation%20Ring%20(Life%20Preserver)&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=S&C=88&O=%7B%22color%22:%2288%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Would this work, or are there better options?
I wonder if I could just thread a key ring through a technic brick.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree with Alex. There's no reason to settle for *a ring*, when you could use *the ring*.

Here's one way to attach it if you want the ring to look like it is hanging down from the door:

[image: Door with ring hanging down]

Comment: That's awesome. I looked at the one ring, but wasn't sure how it would attach. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps [Minifigure, Utensil Ring 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11010) will be a better fit as it is slightly larger than a stud, while life preserver is 3-4 studs in diameter.

[image]

Here how it looks when attached to doors you've mentioned:

[image]